# 2D alpha shapes algorithms in java

Tags: java

I got some 2D points,I tried to calculate the contours in these points.I tried to find some java toolkit or something else.After that I think the alpha shapes could solve this,but I don't know how to figure it out in java.
**For example:**
(I use the opencv to draw the image)
I got these points in the 512*512 images

**Points:**

[image]

I need to calculate the contours like this:

**contour:**

[image]

Comment: OpenCV has [contours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html) functions

Comment: I tried to use opencv contours like this,but it did't work, :
(1)Mat mat = Mat.zeros(512, 512, CvType.CV_8U); //create the 512*512 image;
(2)mat.put(points[i],points[j],255);
(3)Imgproc.findContours(mat,contours,hierachy,Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
Finally,the result of the contours are these original points .That means it make the every point as a contour;

Answer (score -1):

## Solution

I think I solved this issue with the alpha shapes algorithms.

1. Use the alpha shapes algorithms to find the boundary points. This [blog](https://blog.csdn.net/zjjsd195/article/details/122390210) will walk you through that process.
2. Sort the boundary points. First, calucaulate the center point in these points then caculate the angle between the center point and the every other points. Finally, sort the points by the angle.
3. Draw the contour.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uCUT.png]

Comment: In general you shouldn't add links to blog posts.  Instead take the relevant information and add to your post

Comment: Don't link to random external blog posts.  Official  product documentation.  Random tutorials are not ok to link to.  Instead take the relevant information from that post and include in your post with your own words.  Give credit